# HPC clusters running serial jobs

Tags: concurrency, cluster-computing

I have a script that runs on a single core of a cluster. Each serial job is independent. The cluster I use to run on assigns a single core each time you qsub so it assumes ppn=1, and then everyone else can use the other cores. I just submit the number of serial jobs I want to run by looping qsub.

However another cluster we use automatically assigns a single node per user (they have set it up so that a node is the smallest unit rather than a core). Each node has 16 cores. If I then submit my script, it is assigned all 16 cores but it's only running one job. I was wonder therefore how I can run the script and make it use all 16 cores?

One idea I thought of was to run concurrent jobs using another script that loops my current script like this:

for i in {1..16}
do 
./[my script] &
done
wait

I then qsub this with nodes=1,ppn=16. This then I think spawns 16 processes, but I have no idea whether it is actually using all 16 cores or one core that is trying to run all 16 processes. Which is correct? Doing this is also slower than my old way of doing it by about 40% (both methods tested on the old cluster). Is there a better way of doing it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When you say the '16 copies' method runs 40% slower you're talking about timings taken from the old cluster,  ie running 16 copies on one core.  It does not directly suggest that running 16 copies would be slower on 16 cores.

The script you have suggested looks fine and *should* utilise all 16 cores, of course IF your jobs are of variable runtime (ie 15 of the 16 might finish in 5 mins but 1 run for hours) then you're still going to have significant unused cycles.  If this is likely to impact you would need to be more sophisticated and have something looping and spawning processes until the larger workset is done.  Or you could just launch *ALL* the processes you want from 1 script (so you might have 60 or whatever batches running concurrently on 16 processors) and let the os schedule them,  this WILL slow stuff down, perhaps not a lot, your figures above from 16 on 1 core only giving a 40% slowdown *suggest* this is still going to get you 60%+ utilisation up to 256 jobs.

Whatever you do ensure you use the cluster monitoring software to ensure the real, achieved, cpu utilisation is as you expect.

Comment: Ooops, sorry, with regards to the 40% slowdown, that was related to sending my scripts using ppn=16 on the old cluster so it assigns 16 cores rather than just the one to the job and then I spawn 16 processes, so that is the way it should be on the new cluster. I just wanted to test the speeds for the two methods but since my old method of doing things won't work on the new cluster, i resorted to using both methods on the old cluster. Hope that makes sense. You are correct that the jobs take variable time, and I'll need to think a bit on how to optimize that.

Comment: okay and are you measuring cores * runtime as the metric?  If so them 40% may simply be due to the above time variance, ie the 16 core version is 16 * longest_run vs (sum(runtimes) = 16*avg_run).